# Java - Be more precise with double

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision, floating-accuracy

I am currently writing a project for uni, and I was wondering if there are any good practices to be more precise *with* double values. Namely, is there any difference in precision if I write just a long expression directly in the return statement, or is it better if I split the expression into `final` variables (making it also more readable, by the way)? For instance, imagine if I had the following formula: `Math.sin(a) / Math.cos(b) + Math.tan(c) / d`; is it better to write it like follows?

```
final double sinA = Math.sin(a);
final double cosB = Math.cos(b);
final double tanC = Math.tan(c);
return sinA / cosB + tanC / d;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: imho, the compiler will optimize it anyway so both ways might result in the same bytecode. If you are looking for arbitrary precision, you might want to use `BigDecimal`

Comment: Double is precise enough for almost any possible use case. I would ask myself why I think I need more precision and address that. That said if for some reason you do actually need that kind of precision, BigDecimal is the way to go.

Comment: `final` will just make sure that the variable cannot be assigned to after it is initialized (i.e. set to a value). For local variables that's mainly just to benefit maintenance / readability; it doesn't do anything other than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be any difference if your JVM / JIT is implementing IEEE754 correctly which it is required to by the Java Language Specification.

Personally I'd write

```
double ret = Math.sin(a) / Math.cos(b) + Math.tan(c) / d;
return ret;
```

since that allows me to set a line breakpoint on the `return ret;` statement which allows me to inspect the return value without fancy debugging tools which might not be available to you on a production server at 3am! I find the way you've written it to be unclear: relying on a variable name is more prone to refactoring damage than a standard function name.

You can trust that the compiler will optimise out the extra variable `ret`.